# Schemalocations not copied in XSLT with Xalan Pipeline extension

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

i got xml files with "xsi:schemaLocation="location1 location2 ..." and alot of "xmlns:someNs".
While the namespaces will e copied into the new document the schemaLocations are not and i realy can't figure out why they are deleted (all namesspaces and the schemaLocations are also in my stylesheet).

Google says they will be deleted when not used inside the docuent or something like this and i have to add them by myself but well it seems like i can't... I'm using the xalan pipeline to pipe some elementary transformations and now im trying to add a stylesheet at the end of the pipe to just add the locations again. this is my last sheet:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">
      <xsl:text>MYLOCATION</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

I had several variants with an element tag surrounding without the copy... the best result was a doubled root element one with the schemaLocation and one with all the namespaces i really can't figure this out.

Thanks for any help ;)

€:
It seems that all my individual stylesheets are working except the xalan pipe.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:pipe="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/PipeDocument"
                extension-element-prefixes="pipe"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="someschema"
              >

  <xsl:param name="source"/>
  <xsl:param name="target"/>

  <!-- I think this block has no effect -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <pipe:pipeDocument 
          source="{$source}"
          target="{$target}">
      <stylesheet href="sheet1.xsl"/>
      <stylesheet href="sheet2.xsl"/>
      <stylesheet href="sheet3.xsl"/>
    </pipe:pipeDocument>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xalan is not called with -IN and -OUT anymore and i think thats where i lose my locations though i don't understand why the xmlns declarations are still in the output. Every sheet does its own identity transformation and is working as expected if used without the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why the `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes are disappearing from your output, mostly because you haven't shown the input data, the output data, or the templates that produce that output from that input.

The templates you show cannot be producing the result you describe, because they cannot produce any result at all.  (I suspect you have edited them down for brevity, which is a good idea in general, but you've gone too far.)  The template matching `/*` is trying to write an attribute without any element being open in the output; if some variant of this template worked but produced a doubled root element, I would guess it was because you had two `xsl:copy` elements in the template.

Start with a working version of the identity stylesheet, and I expect you will see that both the namespace declarations and the  `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes appear in the output.

For example, consider this stylesheet (which omits templates for comments and processing instructions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply it to this input:

```
<test 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo"
  xmlns:bar="http://example.com/bar"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/foo foo.xsd
                      http://example.com/bar nss/bar.xsd">
  <data/>
</test>
```

The result I get is:

```
<test 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo" 
  xmlns:bar="http://example.com/bar" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://example.com/foo foo.xsd
    http://example.com/bar nss/bar.xsd">
  <data/>
</test>
```

`xsi:schemaLocation` is there.  Namespace declarations are there.  If they aren't there in the output from your existing stylesheet, then step by step change this working code to be more like your existing code.  At the point when the schema location attribute and/or namespaces stop appearing in the output, you've found your error.

If I had to guess, I'd guess that the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute is being dropped by your existing stylesheet because you don't have a template to match it in the input, and/or because the template that matches its parent doesn't include an `xsl:apply-templates` with `select="@*"`.

Comment: The Problem seems to be the xalan pipe beacuse all Fragments for themselves are working as expected. But as soon as they are piped the namespaces get eliminated. I will edit this to my original question.